# Reach UI - intercept click event on menu item select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

Using [`reach-ui`](https://reach.tech/) - Is it possible to prevent/intercept the menu-button (https://reach.tech/menu-button) from closing the menu when clicking/selecting an option? I am wanting to use it for a multi-level dropdown component but that seems to be a blocker as when selecting the option to open the next set of options, it closes the menu